# psutil returns module that has stopped warning

Tags: python

I cannot make a reproducible example for this question; please just scrutinise my logic for misunderstandings or if I'm missing something.

I am trying to write a script that checks on a python application that should be constantly running and if it has stopped working, send me an email. I am using `psutil` to check on running processes. Here's my function that checks if the program in question is running (I'm calling this function at regular intervals).

```
def programRunning():
    cmdLines = []

    for pid in psutil.pids():
            p = psutil.Process(pid)
            if p.name() == "pythonw.exe":
                    cmdLines.append(p.cmdline()[-1])
           #scheduler.py is my script
    if any('scheduler' in process for process in cmdLines):
        return True  
    else:
        return False
```

Now, my main program has produced an error and stopped running, however this function is still returning `True` as in the `cmdLines` `list` I am getting (amongst others):

```
['C:\\Users\\..omitted..\\scheduler.py', ..omitted..]
```

so I am clearly missing something on my understanding of how `psutils` works. Any idea what it is and how to tackle it?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.pids) for `psutil.pids()' say:

> Return a list of current running PIDs. To iterate over all processes and avoid race conditions process_iter() should be preferred.

So it sounds like your process is exiting between the `pids` list being generated, and you reaching that item during iteration.

You probably want to use `psutil.process_iter` which says:

> Return an iterator yielding a Process class instance for all running processes on the local machine. Every instance is only created once and then cached into an internal table which is updated every time an element is yielded. Cached Process instances are checked for identity so that you’re safe in case a PID has been reused by another process, in which case the cached instance is updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately that's not the problem. Even when I'm doing `for p in psutil.process_iter():` I am still getting the `scheduler.py` module as running. Also, if I'm getting what you're saying right that _your process is exiting between the pids list being generated, and you reaching that item during iteration_, this should not be the case because I am doing this check every 5 minutes, not as a one-off. Let me know what you think.